# PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm working on a school project and am having issues getting my program to work. The biggest bottleneck I have right now is that an array assignment is giving me a PLS-00330 error.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED
SET VERIFY OFF

DECLARE
  lv_input1  VARCHAR2(100);
  lv_input2  VARCHAR2(100);
  lv_input3  VARCHAR2(100);
  
  list VARCHAR2(300);
  type lv_strings is varray(3) of varchar2(300);
  COUNT NUMBER;
    
  xnum NUMBER;
  xdate DATE;
  xstring VARCHAR2(30);
  
  
BEGIN
    --count := 1;
    
  lv_strings(1) := '&1';
  lv_strings(2) := '&2';
  lv_strings(3) := '&3';
  
    --TYPE list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(300);
  
  FOR i IN 1..lv_strings.COUNT LOOP
    IF REGEXP_LIKE(lv_strings(i),'^[[:digit:]]*$') OR
       REGEXP_LIKE(lv_strings(i),'^[0-9]{2,2}-[[:alpha:]]{3,3}-([0-9]{2,2}|[0-9]{4,4})$') OR
       REGEXP_LIKE(lv_strings(i),'^[[:alnum:]]*$') THEN
       xnum := lv_strings(i);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  
  --dbms_output.put_line('['+xnum+'] '+'['+xstring+'] '+'['+xdate+']');
  dbms_output.put_line(xnum);
END;
/

SPOOL OFF
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 2):

Several problems going on here. 1) you were trying to use lv_strings as a variable, but it is a type.  I changed the declaration, so now ls_strings_typ is the type, and lv_strings is a variable of that type.  2) lv_strings then needs a constructor. 3) lv_strings needs elements allocated

```
DECLARE
  lv_input1  VARCHAR2(100);
  lv_input2  VARCHAR2(100);
  lv_input3  VARCHAR2(100);
  
  list VARCHAR2(300);
  type lv_strings_typ is varray(3) of varchar2(300); --1
  COUNT NUMBER;
    
  xnum NUMBER;
  xdate DATE;
  xstring VARCHAR2(30);
  lv_strings lv_strings_typ := lv_strings_typ(); -- 1,2
  
BEGIN
    --count := 1;
  lv_strings.EXTEND (3);  --3
  lv_strings(1) := '&1';
```

Answer (score 2):

`lv_strings` is a collection type.  You'd need to declare a local variable of that type that would actually store data.  You'd need to initialize that local collection.  And then you'd need to `extend` it.  This compiles (no idea if it actually does what you want since you haven't told us what it is supposed to do)

```
DECLARE
  lv_input1  VARCHAR2(100);
  lv_input2  VARCHAR2(100);
  lv_input3  VARCHAR2(100);
  
  list VARCHAR2(300);
  type lv_strings is varray(3) of varchar2(300);
  l_strings lv_strings := new lv_strings();
  COUNT NUMBER;
    
  xnum NUMBER;
  xdate DATE;
  xstring VARCHAR2(30);
  
  
BEGIN
    --count := 1;
    
  l_strings.extend(3);
    
  l_strings(1) := '&1';
  l_strings(2) := '&2';
  l_strings(3) := '&3';
  
    --TYPE list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(300);
  
  FOR i IN 1..l_strings.COUNT LOOP
    IF REGEXP_LIKE(l_strings(i),'^[[:digit:]]*$') OR
       REGEXP_LIKE(l_strings(i),'^[0-9]{2,2}-[[:alpha:]]{3,3}-([0-9]{2,2}|[0-9]{4,4})$') OR
       REGEXP_LIKE(l_strings(i),'^[[:alnum:]]*$') THEN
       xnum := l_strings(i);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  
  --dbms_output.put_line('['+xnum+'] '+'['+xstring+'] '+'['+xdate+']');
  dbms_output.put_line(xnum);
END;
/
```

Personally, I can't think of a time that I'd want to use a `varray` rather than a nested table or an associative array.  But maybe you're just learning all the collection types.